# how do i get the previous 3 months using the current month in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rss

im creating an rss reader that lists the news feeds from the last 3 months. how do i get the feeds of the last 3 months relative to the current date? right now i have a list of all the feeds.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that you can't access more than the ten items from the last two weeks of an RSS feed, then the problem is not on your side: most RSS feeds only offer the N most recent items from the source.

Comment: right.. what i meant was i wanted to limit the number of feeds i get. i want to only display the feeds that are within the last three months since im retrieving feeds that are from a longer period.

Comment: @lct: It's still not clear: do you want to test when the feed was last updated, or do you want to reduce bandwidth consumption by not downloading older items within a feed?